# Create Calculated Column based on another table with select statement is too slow in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, calculated-columns

I need to create a calculated column that looks at the Field called Forecast Multiplier and if it is 1 use the number in field fp.month1 then if it is 1.5 use fp.month1 and 1/2 of fp.month2 and so on up to 12 months.  So I figured I would create a function and then base the calculated column on the function.  Here is the function:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MinInventory as int;
    DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @WeekNumber as int = DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @MyDate), 0), @MyDate) + 1
    DECLARE @MONTH1 as int = convert(int, [dbo].[ForecastPivot].MONTH1)

    SELECT @MinInventory =
        CASE 
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 1 Then fp.month1
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 1.5 Then fp.month1 + (fp.month2 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 2 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 2.5 Then fp.month2 + fp.month2 + (fp.month3 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 3 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 3.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + (fp.month4 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 4 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 4.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + (fp.month5 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 5.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + (fp.month6 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 6 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 6.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + (fp.month7 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 7 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 7.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + (fp.month8 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 8 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 8.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + (fp.month9 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 9 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + fp.month9
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 9.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + fp.month9 + (fp.month10 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 10 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + fp.month9 + fp.month10
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 10.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + fp.month9 + fp.month10 + (fp.month11 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 11 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + fp.month9 + fp.month10 + fp.month11
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 11.5 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + fp.month9 + fp.month10 + fp.month11 + (fp.month12 * .5)
        when @ForecastMultiplier = 12 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + fp.month5 + fp.month6 + fp.month7 + fp.month8 + fp.month9 + fp.month10 + fp.month11 + fp.month12
        end
    FROM [dbo].[MinimumProductInfoes] mpi
    join [dbo].[ForecastPivot] fp on fp.EQCODE = @EquivCode AND fp.FWHSE = @region
    RETURN Round(@MinInventory, 0)
END
```

The function works correctly but it is very slow.  It takes about 10 seconds to run it once. The table I am going to use this on has a few hundred rows, so this would take a few minutes to execute; not acceptable.  How can I speed this up?  If I cannot I am thinking about running a job overnight to do this.

Comment: @marc_s  Thank you, is sql-server.  Will add it to the title too

Comment: I have a feeling that this is a scalar function you are showing us and that your actual query is something that calls this. Scalar functions in sql server are horrifically bad for performance. Not sure why you have so many variables defined in here as many of them are not used at all. This could be converted to inline table valued function pretty easily which will outperform the scalar function by leaps and bounds.

Comment: @SeanLange MyDate and WeekNumber I was going to use to make the weeks rolling but that would slow it down more. I removed them and Month1.  Sorry I will reflect that in my code. Yes it is an scaler function.  How do I convert it to an inline table valued function?

Comment: you wont be able to use an inline tvf in a computed column. if you abandon that idea you can make a view with the additional column required. you havent provided table definitions or sample data though that might have encouraged me to look further.

Comment: @MartinSmith would the view be significantly quicker?

Comment: possibly, if you are able to write it in a set based way rather than RBAR as per the function.

Comment: @MartinSmith what do you mean in a set based way rather than RBAR?

Comment: RBAR = Row By Agonizing Row  (Cursor based and iteration of rows)  SET BASED is when you manipulate many rows at once via a single query