# Case statement in SQL Server with rolling weeks - easier way?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a case statement (inside a view) that tests 2 variables and outputs a value for another field. The 2 variables it tests are ForecastMultiplier and a function that gets the current week number. Forecast Multiplier means how many months to take in to effect. I then have a table with 12 months of forecast which I use to figure out how much on hand inventory we should have.

Here are some examples:

- If Forecast Multiplier = 1 and we are in the first week of the month then I will take all of Month1 Forecast (which is the current month).
- If Forecast Multiplier = 1 and we are in the second week of the month then I will take 75% of Month1 Forecast plus 25% of Month2 Forecast.
- If Forecast Multiplier = 5 and we are in the first week of the month then I will take Month1 Forecast plus Month2 Forecast plus Month3 Forecast plus Month4 Forecast plus Month5 Forecast
- If Forecast Multiplier = 5 and we are in the third week of the month then I will take 50% of Month1 Forecast plus Month2 Forecast plus Month3 Forecast plus Month4 Forecast plus Month5 Forecast plus 25% of Month6 Forecast

and this needs to be done for forecast multipliers of .5, 1.5, etc as well.  So you can see how, using a simple select case will get very cumbersome.

Here is some of the case statement, so you can see:

```
CASE 
    when mpi.UseForecast = 0 then mpi.MinimumOnHandQuantity
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 1 Then fp.month1
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 2 Then (fp.month1 * .75) + (fp.MONTH2 * .25)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 3 Then (fp.month1 * .50) + (fp.MONTH2 * .50)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 4 Then (fp.month1 * .25) + (fp.MONTH2 * .75)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1.5 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 1 Then fp.month1 + (fp.month2 * .5)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1.5 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 2 Then (fp.month1 * .75) + (fp.month2 * .5)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1.5 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 3 Then (fp.month1 * .50) + (fp.month2 * .5)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 1.5 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 4 Then (fp.month1 * .25) + (fp.month2 * .5)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 2 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 1 Then fp.month1 + fp.month2
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 2 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 2 Then (fp.month1 * .75) + fp.month2 + (fp.MONTH3 * .25)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 2 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 3 Then (fp.month1 * .50) + fp.month2 + (fp.MONTH3 * .50)
    when mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 2 and dbo.GetWeekNumber() = 4 Then (fp.month1 * .25) + fp.month2 + (fp.MONTH3 * .75)
```

The SQL statement works but there are a few issues with it.  It is cumbersome. It is getting slower the more Months I add to it (it will never go more than 12 months).  Also, it doesn't take the months with 5 weeks in to account.  Finally, if possible we would prefer rolling days, but by this method it is nearly impossible.  Is there a way of doing this through stored procedures and/ or functions? btw, I originally was doing the select statement in a Scaler function but it was very slow, so now I am trying the view.

What I am looking for is a better way to achieve this same result or as I mentioned in the last paragraph, a better result.

Here is the Schema and some data:

MinimumProductInfoes (MPI):

```
Code Region UseForecast ForecastMultipler MinimumOnHand
---- ------ ----------- ----------------- -------------
1    R1     0           0                 50
1    R2     1           2                 0
2    R1     1           4.5               0
2    R3     1           3                 0
3    R1     1           12                0
```

ForecastPivot (FP):

```
Code  Region  Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6 Month7 ... Month12
----  ------  ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------     -------
1     R1      200    200    50     75     200    50     50         80
1     R2      500    500    500    500    500    500    500        500
2     R1      1000   0      0      0      0      0      0          0
2     R3      25     1000   1000   1000   1000   1000   1000       1000
```

Comment: This sure looks a lot like your other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581824/create-calculated-column-based-on-another-table-with-select-statement-is-too-slo However now you have added a scalar function to the mix which will make it even slower.

Comment: @SeanLange, my other question was when I first started it (and before I added the rolling weeks in to it) and it was a scalerfunction itself and very slow.  Someone suggested moving it to a view, which I did first which was much quicker, so I then started on the next step of adding the rolling weeks in. As I add more and more rolling weeks, it gets slower, and as you can see looks very cumbersome, so I wanted to see if there was a better way to do this.  So my last question was based on the same project but I didn't add the rolling weeks yet and was not in a view.

Comment: The performance issue is because of that scalar function in there.

Comment: @SeanLange how would I get the week number without a scaler function?

Comment: This screams for a Calendar Table.

Comment: What flavor and version of SQL?

Comment: @Shawn, Sql Server 2008 R2.  What is a calender Table? never heard of it?

Comment: And what happens when the WeekNumber is 5?

Comment: Calendar Table >> https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Shawn, I haven't figured out how to do the 5 week yet.  I was thinking about maybe keeping it the same as 4 weeks, because it is only 2 months a year and would not have that much effect.  If you have a better solution, that is why I posted on here.

Comment: Can you provide a sample schema and a bit of sample data?

Comment: And your forecast multiplier goes from 1-12, .5-12.5 or something else?

Comment: @Shawn, my forecast multipler goes 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3 -> 12  How do you want me to provide the sample data?

Comment: Basically some what to show the basics of what your tables and your data look like. Preferably before it comes to this view. I'm assuming that fp.monthX can go all the way from month1 to month12? There may be an easier way to get to the data you're looking for. That's where the schema and fake data help.

Comment: @Shawn, made a few changes to the question let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Is ForecastPivot an actual table or a view pivoted from another table?

Comment: @Shawn, it is a view but only because it is working off a table in Oracle with the same exact data and that table has a datestamp field which sql server doesn't like, so I needed to create a view with OPENQUERY()

Comment: @Shawn, did you have any ideas? I am looking at Itslex answer if that can help

Comment: @djblois The getWeekNumber() function is going to put a hurting on your performance. I'd still look at doing a simple calendar table (which every database should have anyway) and using that to calculate your week number.

Comment: Is your ForecastPivot able to calculate the data in Month1,... by days instead of by month? It would be possible to calculate a forecast by days, but not the way that table is currently set up. It would also be just as well to not pivot it beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/078150/3)

**Schema Setup**: *(SQLFiddle uses MS SQL 2014, but this will still work in 2008.)*

```
CREATE TABLE MPI ( Code int, Region varchar(5), UseForecast bit
    , ForecastMultiplier decimal(5,1), MinimumOnHand int ) ;
INSERT INTO MPI ( Code, Region, UseForecast, ForecastMultiplier, MinimumOnHand )
VALUES 
      ( 1,'R1',0,0,50 )
    , ( 1,'R2',1,2,0)
    , ( 2,'R1',1,4.5,0)
    , ( 2,'R3',1,3,0)
    , ( 3,'R1',1,12,0)
;

CREATE TABLE FP ( Code int,  Region varchar(5), Month1 int, Month2 int
    , Month3 int, Month4 int, Month5 int, Month6 int, Month7 int
    , Month8 int, Month9 int, Month10 int, Month11 int, Month12 int ) ;
INSERT INTO FP (Code, Region, Month1, Month2, Month3, Month4, Month5
    , Month6, Month7, Month8, Month9, Month10, Month11, Month12 )
VALUES 
      ( 1,'R1',200,200,50,75,200,50,50,50,50,50,50,80 )
    , ( 1,'R2',500,500,500,500,500,500,500,50,50,50,50,500 )
    , ( 2,'R1',1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,50,50,50,0 )
    , ( 2,'R3',25,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,50,50,50,50,1000 )
;
```

**Build Simple Calendar Table**:

*NOTE: The calendar table is for general use in your database, so add whatever calculations you need. I often use a modified version of Aaron Bertrand's example: https://github.com/shawnoden/SQL_Stuff/blob/master/sql_CreateDateDimension.sql*

```
/* #dim is just a temp holding table for intermediate calculations. */
CREATE TABLE #dim (
      theDate           date        PRIMARY KEY
    , theDay            AS DATEPART(day, theDate)           --int
    , theWeek           AS DATEPART(week, theDate)          --int 
    , theMonth          AS DATEPART(month, theDate)         --int
    , theYear           AS DATEPART(year, theDate)          --int
    , yyyymmdd          AS CONVERT(char(8), theDate, 112)   /* yyyymmdd */
    , mm_dd_yy          AS CONVERT(char(10), theDate, 101)  /* mm/dd/yyyy */
);

/**************************************************************************/
/* Use the catalog views to generate as many rows as we need. */

INSERT INTO #dim ( theDate ) 
SELECT d
FROM (
    SELECT d = DATEADD(day, rn - 1, '20170101')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, '20160101', '20190101')) 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.object_id)
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
        ORDER BY s1.object_id
    ) AS x
) AS y;

/* Now create the final ref table for the dates. */
CREATE TABLE refDateDimension
(
      DateKey             int         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , theDate             date        NOT NULL
    , theDay              tinyint     NOT NULL  
    , WeekOfMonth         tinyint     NOT NULL
    , theMonth            tinyint     NOT NULL
    , theYear             int         NOT NULL
    , mm_dd_yy            char(10)    NOT NULL   /* mm/dd/yyyy */
);

/* Insert data in the dimension table. */
INSERT refDateDimension WITH (TABLOCKX)
SELECT
      DateKey              = CONVERT(int, yyyymmdd)
    , theDate              = theDate
    , theDay               = CONVERT(tinyint, theDay)
    , WeekOfMonth          = CONVERT(tinyint
                              , DENSE_RANK() OVER 
                                (PARTITION BY theYear, theMonth 
                                 ORDER BY theWeek)
                           )
    , theMonth             = CONVERT(tinyint, theMonth)
    , theYear              = theYear
    , mm_dd_yy             = mm_dd_yy
FROM #dim
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

/* CLEANUP */
DROP TABLE #dim ;
```

**Now we use the calendar table to quickly find the week number.**:

```
SELECT s1.Code
  , s1.Region
  , CEILING(s1.ForecastMinOnHand) AS ForecastMinOnHand /* Round up to even number. */
FROM (
  SELECT MPI.Code, MPI.Region
    --, MPI.UseForecast, MPI.ForecastMultiplier, d.WeekOfMonth
    , CASE 
          WHEN MPI.UseForecast = 0          THEN MPI.MinimumOnHand
          WHEN MPI.ForecastMultiplier = 1    THEN CASE d.WeekOfMonth 
                                                      WHEN 1 THEN FP.Month1 
                                                      WHEN 2 THEN (FP.Month1*.75) + (FP.Month2*.25)
                                                      WHEN 3 THEN (FP.Month1*.5) + (FP.Month2*.5)
                                                      ELSE (FP.Month1*.25) + (FP.Month2*.75)
                                                 END
          WHEN MPI.ForecastMultiplier = 2    THEN CASE d.WeekOfMonth 
                                                      WHEN 1 THEN FP.Month1 + FP.Month2
                                                      WHEN 2 THEN (FP.Month1*.75) + FP.Month2 + (FP.Month3*.25)
                                                      WHEN 3 THEN (FP.Month1*.5) + FP.Month2 + (FP.Month3*.5)
                                                      ELSE (FP.Month1*.25) + FP.Month2 + (FP.Month3*.75)
                                                 END     
          WHEN MPI.ForecastMultiplier = 3    THEN CASE d.WeekOfMonth 
                                                      WHEN 1 THEN FP.Month1 + FP.Month2 + FP.Month3
                                                      WHEN 2 THEN (FP.Month1*.75) + FP.Month2 + FP.Month3 + (FP.Month4*.25)
                                                      WHEN 3 THEN (FP.Month1*.5) + FP.Month2 + FP.Month3 + (FP.Month4*.5)
                                                      ELSE (FP.Month1*.25) + FP.Month2 + FP.Month3 + (FP.Month4*.75)
                                                 END   
          WHEN MPI.ForecastMultiplier = 4.5  THEN CASE d.WeekOfMonth 
                                                      WHEN 1 THEN FP.month1 + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + (FP.month5*.5)
                                                      WHEN 2 THEN (FP.Month1*.75) + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + (FP.Month5*.75)
                                                      WHEN 3 THEN (FP.Month1*.5) + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + FP.Month5
                                                      ELSE (FP.Month1*.25) + fp.month2 + fp.month3 + fp.month4 + FP.Month5 + (FP.Month6*.25)
                                                 END     

     END AS ForecastMinOnHand
     --, MPI.*, FP.*
  FROM MPI 
  INNER JOIN refDateDimension d ON CAST(getDate() AS date) = d.theDate 
  INNER JOIN FP ON MPI.Code = FP.Code
    AND MPI.Region = FP.Region
) s1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/078150/3/0)**:

```
| Code | Region | ForecastMinOnHand |
|------|--------|-------------------|
|    1 |     R1 |                50 |
|    1 |     R2 |              1000 |
|    2 |     R1 |               750 |
|    2 |     R3 |              2269 |
```

My main purpose of using the calendar table here is that it takes away the `GetWeekNumber()` function and saves a bunch of processing cycles. It will also let your SQL optimizer run a bit more efficiently. In general, you would add a lot more columns to it to account for the time calculations you need elsewhere. It's a utility table. And **extremely** handy.

I still think the long `CASE` statement can be distilled down a bit. If you have the ability to edit the `ForecastPivot` view, you should be able to get at some of this data a little easier without a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement might become less cumbersome and shorter by a factor of almost 4 if you combine the cases for one Multiplier like:

```
CASE WHEN mpi.ForecastMultiplier = 2 THEN (5 - dbo.GetWeekNumber()) * 0.25 * fp.month1 + fp.month2 + (dbo.GetWeekNumber() - 1) * 0.25 * fp.month3
```

Somehow I think this also still works for week 5.